# Group Multiple Tables in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a very simple SQL query:

```
SELECT r.SpaceID, Count (*), SpaceCode 
FROM Rider r JOIN Spaces s 
ON r.SpaceID = s.SpaceID
GROUP BY r.SpaceID, s.SpaceCode
```

Please note that my group by clause is on multiple tables, I want to do the same in LINQ, I know how to group single table, but about multiple tables I have no idea.

Comment: Just see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435485/linq-group-by-multiple-tables

Comment: Thanks, i've already seen that, but Concat does not seems like a good option, moreover the structure for both of my table is too different, so this is not gonna work for me,

Answer (score 81, accepted):

For grouping multiple tables you can do as:

```
group new { r,s } by new { r.SpaceID, s.SpaceCode }
```

Comment: How can I sum others columns from `r`, or `s` in the `select new`?

Answer (score 41):

this might help:

```
(
    from r in db.Rider
    join s in db.Spaces
        on r.SpaceID equals s.SpaceID
    group new { r,s } by new { r.SpaceID, s.SpaceCode }
    into grp
    select new
    {
        Count=grp.Count(),
        grp.Key.SpaceID,
        grp.Key.SpaceCode
    }
)
```

Where db is the database context

Comment: Select part should be:
`select new
    {
        Count = grp.Count(),
        grp.Key.SpaceID,
        grp.Key.SpaceCode
    }`

Comment: @Arion: Petr Behensky's correction still doesn't appear in your solution.

Comment: In this case, how to get other fields of r, s in select new? grp.r or grp.s seem not working.

Comment: How can I sum a column like `grp.Sum(x => x.Col1)`? I'm trying but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command.

```
grp.Sum(x => x.r.Col1)
```

It works well.