# Obtaining multiple fields with LINQ group statement

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using the following grouping within my LINQ statement.

I have figured out how to obtain the maximum date from the 'notes' table, however am struggling to find an efficient way to find the 'NoteText' property of the same record (highlighted with ???? in both places)

```
group new { t1, notes } by new
{
    t1.Opportunity_Title
} into g

let latestNoteDate = g.Max(uh => uh.notes.Date)
let latestNote = g.Max(uh => uh.notes.NoteText) < needs to be latest note for record above ^

select new PipelineViewModel
{
    LastNoteDate = latestNoteDate,
    LastNote = latestNote,  ????
}).Take(howMany);
```

Comment: You should try this one

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724719/group-multiple-tables-in-linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```
let latestNote = latestNoteDate == null ? null : 
                 g.First(x => x.notes.Date == latestNoteDate).NoteText
```

Comment: If you are not checking for `null` don't use `FirstOrDefault`, use `First` instead.