# Entity Framework GroupBy and sum over three tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I wrote a SQL query to get a overview of sales revenue per car manufacturer.

Simple enough:

```
select 
    sum(s.Price * s.NumberOfCars) as Revenue, m.Name
from
    Sale as s
join 
    Car as c on c.Id = s.CarId
join 
    Manufacturer as m on m.Id = c.ManufacturerId
group by 
    m.Name
```

That returns the following output:

[image]

Does anybody have an idea how to accomplish that with Entity Framework?

I tried this Linq:

```
 var salez = from s in _context.Sale
             join c in _context.Car on s.CarId equals c.Id
             join m in _context.Manufacturer on c.ManufacturerId equals m.Id
             group m by m.Name into g
             select new Manufacturer()
                        { 
                            Name = g.Key,
                            Revenue = g.Sum(s => s.)
                        };
```

I somehow can't build the sum, as the table "s" is not available in the group "g".

I have also found quite similar questions, but none covered this case.

Similar question:

[Group Multiple Tables in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724719/group-multiple-tables-in-linq)

Further, I have tried the follwing:

```
SaleGroupManu = gret
    .GroupBy(s => s.Car)
    .Select(sc => new Car()
    {
        Umsatz = sc.Sum(s => s.Umsatz),
        Manufacturer = sc.Key.Manufacturer
    }).GroupBy(sc => sc.Manufacturer)
    .Select(scm => new Manufacturer()
    {
        Name = scm.Key.Name,
        Umsatz = scm.Sum(s => s.Umsatz)
    }).ToList();
```

But I don't find it very elegant, as I have to group by Car first, whilst with SQL, I can group by Manufacturer directly. It works, but is there any better idea?

I have tried raw sql, but it gave me errors, such as "The required column 'Id' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have eventually worked it out, with the "!."-Syntax I didn't know about.

```
SaleGroupManu = sale
    .Include(s => s.Car)
    .Include(s => s.Car!.Manufacturer).ToList()
    .GroupBy(s => s.Car!.Manufacturer)
    .Select(ms => new Manufacturer()
    {
        Name = ms.Key!.Name,
        Revenue = ms.Sum(s => s.Revenue)
    }).ToList();
```

Update for the application: i'm moving away from entity again... the database-migrations are comfortable, but it's easy to blow your leg off, if you use it too much. simple sql files for migrations and dapper for querying is way more managable. plus, entity also always uses "exec_sqlquery(...)" instead of just the query itself. that was also sth. that put me off. basically the conclusion that Youtuber Tim Corey led me to.

Comment: This addition is meaningless.

Comment: @GertArnold not sure if it's meaningless to everybody. it was more in the sense of warning people about entity. but of course, if you're pro-entity, my addition is indeed annoying, as "today everybody is against entity....". i see that not everyone agrees with this (my) opinion, but i don't see why it's meaningless... if some people agree, it's maybe not. it's indeed an opinion. and i see that opinions are not welcomed at so... as if there is any person seeing the "objective truth" about anything... but i digress -.-

Comment: It's totally irrelevant to the question. We don't ventilate opinions here for no reason.

Comment: @GertArnold my opinion is in certainly an opinion. but i guess you are the one ventilating right now :o

Comment: Yeah, but not in an answer. And it's not an opinion, it's standing SO policy.

Comment: @GertArnold in fact, it happens quite often that people on stackoverflow "discourage someone to do something in a certain way". now, how is this different? Like "yeah, you shouldn't write games in MVC pattern...". i've looked at your profile, you seem to be quite the expert at entity... and if you still insist, that it violated some policy, how about posting the link to said policy? people warn about stuff on so all the time and very often, people like it when commentors warn the questioner. in this case, i warned myself... i sort of get it, but not precisely.

Comment: @GertArnold or is it that it's fine to discourage from usage of xyz if there is a consensus that it's bad, but not if it's disputed / controversal (aka. "highly opinionated)? and who says where the consensus is about sth?

Comment: Well, if you insist that the latter part is helpful, please take it to meta.stackoverflow.com. I'm not going to discuss this any further.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your working sql query directly into EF via `DbSet.SqlQuery()` as documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Answer (score 0):

The database model and the mapped classes allow for easy and efficient querying what you want.

This LINQ query should be translated directly into SQL that looks closely like the SQL query you'd like to emulate: it performs the `GROUP BY` and aggregation in the database and just returns the final results:

```cs
_context.Sales
    .GroupBy(s => s.Car.Manufacturer.Name)
    .Select(grp => new Manufacturer()
    {
        Name = grp.Key,
        Revenue = grp.Sum(s => s.Revenue)
    }).ToList();
```

This is far more efficient than pulling all data into memory, with `Include`s and all, and then aggregating.

As Tim Corey says: I don't hate EF, only the way people sometimes use it.