# Counts of two table based on dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two tables  **Registers** and **IAApplications** as below

Registers

```
Name                                   Email                           Creationdate
Mazhar                                Khan@gmail.com              2018-09-02 13:08:32.303
mohan                                 m@gmail.com                 2018-09-01 13:08:32.303
kjdj                                  k@gmail.com                 2018-09-01 13:08:32.303
```

IAApplications

```
Title                Sector                   SubmissionDate
 kk                     jj                  2018-09-03 13:08:32.303 
 kk                     jj                  2018-09-02 13:08:32.303 
 mm                     tt                  2018-09-01 13:08:32.303
```

I need below ouput for my report

```
Date            New Registratio          New Application   
09-03-2018         0                         1
09-02-2018         1                         1             
09-01-2018         2                         1
```

I tried below code getting wrong data

```
  var Regs = from o in db.Registers
                   select new { A = (o.Creationdate) };
        var Apps = from c in db.IAApplications
                   select new { A = (c.SubmissionDate) };


        var result = (from x in Regs.Concat(Apps)
                      group x by x.A into og
                      select new { Date = og.Key, Reg = og.Count(), App = og.Count() }).ToList();
```

I am getting wrong result as below image in my local system i have lot of data but not mention above table question.

[image]

I know some thing wrong in my query that's why date is not showing group by and also data counts

[I have prefer this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435485/linq-group-by-multiple-tables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you must have the filters `dateStart` and `dateEnd`

Then, for each date in that range, you check if there is a registration or an application in the date given

```
var dateStart = new DateTime(2018,9,1);
var dateEnd = DateTime.Now;
var list = new List<Tuple<DateTime, int, int>>(); // structure to store DateTime, New Registratio, New Application   
for(var i = dateStart; i.Date <= dateEnd.Date;  i = i.AddDay(1))
{
    list.Add(Tuple.Create(i,
                          db.Registers.Count(r => r.Creationdate.Date == i.Date), 
                          db.IAApplications.Count(r => r.SubmissionDate.Date == i.Date)));
}
var result = list.Select(og => new { Date = og.Item1, Reg = og.Item2, App = og.Item3 }).ToList();
```

If you don't have `dateStart` and `dateEnd` predefined, these values come from `min/max` of 2 tables

Comment: I am getting error in second like of 'Admonth(1) and fourth line'  like this error: 'System.Datetime' does not contain a definition for 'AddMonth' and no extension method 'AddMonth' accepting as first argument of type 'System.DateTime' . @Thierry V

Comment: @mazhar AddMonths!!

Comment: I have to pass static start date and end date  date na and my start date is 1 sept 2018 and end date is till now, can u update this in above answer. Thierry V

Comment: @mazhar dateStart and dateEnd is just the variable for demonstration purpose. They contain what ever values. The important part in the loop.

Comment: I am very new to linq, please update full answer I am searching since 2 days this query its very important to me if you update full answer. @Thierry V

Comment: In my website i have to show the Registersand and IAApplications from 1 sept 2018 to till now, because admin will check daily how many registration and application came, hope you understand my things. @Thierry V

Comment: Please check i am getting error in this line.  list.Add(Tuple.Create(i,
                                      db.Registers.Count(r => r.Creationdate.Date == i.Date),
                                      db.IAApplications.Count(r => r.SubmissionDate.Date == i.Date))); . @Thierry V

Comment: I am getting this error : The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported. @Thierry V

Comment: Are you there?. @Thierry V

Comment: Thank you for your support now i am getting correct data and replace your line to this :  list.Add(Tuple.Create(i, db.Registers.Count(r => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(r.Creationdate) == i.Date),
                                      db.IAApplications.Count(r => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(r.SubmissionDate) == i.Date))); .@Thierry V

Comment: @mazhar Glad to help you

Comment: I'd like to point out that this solution executes two DB queries per date. If the interval is long or the data is queried frequently, **this may lead to poor performance**.

Comment: I am trying to add one more table counts db.Quality.Count(r => r.QDate.Date == i.Date) but q= og.Item4 is giving error. @Thierry V

Answer (score 0):

The task can be solved using a single round-trip to the DB:

```
var regCounts = db.Registers.GroupBy(reg => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(reg.Creationdate),
    (key, group) => new { Date = key, Value = group.Count() });

var appCounts = db.IAApplications.GroupBy(app => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(app.SubmissionDate),
    (key, group) => new { Date = key, Value = group.Count() });

var leftJoin = regCounts.SelectMany(reg => appCounts.Where(app => app.Date == reg.Date).DefaultIfEmpty(),
    (reg, app) => new { reg.Date, RegCount = reg.Value, AppCount = app != null ? app.Value : 0 });

var rightJoin = appCounts.SelectMany(app => regCounts.Where(reg => reg.Date == app.Date).DefaultIfEmpty(),
    (app, reg) => new { app.Date, RegCount = reg != null ? reg.Value : 0, AppCount = app.Value });

var data = leftJoin.Union(rightJoin) // "full join" regCounts and appCounts
    .OrderByDescending(r => r.Date)
    .ToArray();
```

Unfortunately, LINQ To Entities doesn't support full outer join but it can be simulated as a union of a left outer and right outer join as shown above.